# Confusion regarding the linkage of identifiers

Tags: c, linker, language-lawyer, identifier

I'm reading the C Standard [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and faced some misunderstanding about linkage. As specified in `6.2.2. Linkages of objects`:

> 5 If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no
>   storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it
>   were declared with the storage-class specifier extern. ***If the
>   declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no
>   storage-class specifier, its linkage is external.***

So I guessed that there is no difference between `extern` and no storage-class specifier in the declaration of identifiers of objects with file scope.

Let's condider the following example:

`test.h`:

```
#ifndef _TEST_H
#define _TEST_H

int a;

void increment();

#endif //_TEST_H
```

`test.c`:

```
#include "test.h"

void increment(){
    a += 2;
}
```

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    increment();
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
}
```

Since `a` is declared to have external linkage (file scope, no storage class specifier) `a = 2` is printed as expected.

So I replaced the declaration of `a` to have `extern` specifier and expected no difference (according to the `6.2.2#5` I cited above):

`test.h`:

```
#ifndef _TEST_H
#define _TEST_H

extern int a; // <---- Note extern here

void increment();

#endif //_TEST_H
```

But now the linker complains:

```
CMakeFiles/bin.dir/main.c.o: In function `main':
main.c:37: undefined reference to `a'
liblibtest.a(test.c.o): In function `increment':
test.c:4: undefined reference to `a'
test.c:4: undefined reference to `a'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How does the Standard explain this behavior? Since identifiers have the same linkage in both cases I expected the linker behavior to be the same too.

Comment: Do not omit the `extern` from variables declared in headers.  If you do, every file that includes the header ends up defining the variable.  See [How do I use `extern` to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204) for the full story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the fist case `int a`, is a *tentative definition*.

In second case, a *definition* for `a` is missing, only declaration is there. That's why linker complains.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.9.2

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and
>   without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier `static`, constitutes a
>   *tentative definition*. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an
>   identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then
>   the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
>   identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer
>   equal to 0.

Comment: So is the tentative definition treated by linker as a regular definition? The term _tentative_ is little bit confusing in this context.

Comment: @SomeName Why confusing? I feel, the mention of _" and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier,"_ perfectly justifies the "tentative", dont you think?

Comment: It also hinges on the common extension noted in C11 [Annex J.5.11 Multiple external definitions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.5.11): _There may be more than one external definition for the identifier of an object, with or without the explicit use of the keyword extern; if the definitions disagree, or more than one is initialized, the behavior is undefined (6.9.2)._ This is strictly an extension to the standard, albeit one that is probably more frequently encountered than not.

Comment: The reason that `int a;` at the top of the file is tentative is that you're allowed to have `int a = 99;` further down the same source file.  This is not tentative and completes the previous tentative definition.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler _or more than one is initialized_ But I expected that linker will complain in this case since more then one definition, no?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Could you please give an example of such UB?

Comment: @SomeName: It depends on whether your linker allows the 'common extension' or not.  Some linkers won't allow it at all; others allow it by default.  There are options to C++ compilers to override the ODR — One Definition Rule — that the standard officially requires.  The business with `int a;` in a header is not reliably portable because the standard says it does not have to work (in fact, the standard says it shouldn't work, but J.5.11 is a 'get out of jail free' card that let's you off the hook on many systems).

Comment: @SomeName: An example of UB is: `file1.c` has `int a;` at the top of the file, and `file2.c` has `double a;` at the top of the file.  If those files are linked, the definitions disagree and the result is undefined behaviour — the standard doesn't mandate what will happen and anything is allowed.  In practice, it usually means that the longer definition is used — that's the other part of the 'COMMON' heritage from Fortran (at least, Fortran 77 or earlier; I've not used the later versions), where COMMON has a specific peculiar meaning, and EQUIVALENCE is another interesting topic.